# get image from https url ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am not getting the image from url.i am not able to find Proper solution on StackOverflow. I've found two ways to convert image from URL but they are not working

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mastersoftwaretechnologies.com:8014/uploads/50x50/6455.png"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

And second method is

```
    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"https://mastersoftwaretechnologies.com:8014/uploads/50x50/6455.png" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"img url ==%@",imageURL);
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
UIImage *MYimage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

**UIImage** is returning nil in both conditions

i have added **NStransportsecurity**.

Comment: are you added NSTransportSecurity in yiur app

Comment: seems you url has something problem can't able to see image in browser.Did you can?

Comment: yes ..i have added transport security.

Comment: url is working in safari @DS Dharma

Comment: you need to wait for sime times

Comment: Sir,image is showing in postman and browser..

Comment: There is some permission issue from your server side. Otherwise code is ohk.

Comment: Hay @VarinderSingh how to resolve this issue.

Comment: @chirag Please make the url with Http . because some https links not working with images in iOS.

Comment: @VarinderSingh But my image url with https.

Comment: bro ..you can try with answer in my post. if any code is working, then i will mark as accepted answer

Comment: It is solved with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44623292/8385972)

Comment: And set this method [self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] options:SDWebImageAllowInvalidSSLCertificates convertTo:ImageConversionTypeCIRCULARPROFILEPICTURE];

Answer (score 0):

Better to use SDWebImage library for downloading the image, its managing lots of work at backend including memory management and cache.

[SdWebImageLibrary](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Install using `pod 'SDWebImage-ProgressView'`

Use following methods with this url `https://test.com:/image.png`

```
[self.imageView bravo_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:placeholder_qrcode] options:SDWebImageAllowInvalidSSLCertificates convertTo:ImageConversionTypeCIRCULARPROFILEPICTURE];
```

Comment: i am not setting image on UIImageview  from URL. i only need UIImage.

Comment: From UIImageView you can get image easily UIImageView.image

Answer (score 0):

This problem caused because of your ssl certificates or server side restrictions.

I have checked your image url and got following error message with `SDWebImage`.

Try with to solve this error message.

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x1700504d0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://mastersoftwaretechnologies.com:8014/uploads/50x50/6455.png, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://mastersoftwaretechnologies.com:8014/uploads/50x50/6455.png, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}

**Note - You need to set ATS as per your ssl certificate.**

**OR**

Run this command in terminal for more explanation.

```
nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://fmastersoftwaretechnologies.com --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"

[profileImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code with valid url.

```
 NSString *url = @"";
 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                                   if ( !error )
                                   {
                                       UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                       self.myImage.image = image;

                                   }
                               }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link which you have provided have some restriction and its connection is closed for some reason.
[image]

If the link is correct or there is no restriction you can able to see the image content in browser while ping the link into it.

For liable image download, if you want to do native method you can go for:

**Native image downloader:**

```
{
 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil]
NSString *urlString = @"http//:........";//url link
urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadSongTask = [session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
 [downloadTask resume];
}
```

You will be getting download progress and complete delegate call back.

**SDWebImage:**

```
1. Install -> pod 'SDWebImage'
2. Import this header to class where you are downloading image,
3. Code snippet:
{   
 [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default"]options:SDWebImageAllowInvalidSSLCertificates];
}
```